# I can't run '% npm init' in VS Code Terminal

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, sass, init

I'm learning to use SASS with an online course and the structure installs node so we can then install SASS with NPM.

After installing node he initiates NPM in the VS Code terminal with '% npm init' command and the program asks for some basic data about the project we're starting but I get this error when I run it:

````
% : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ % npm init
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:PSObject) [ForEach-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand ```

Is this command correct? What should I fix?
````

Comment: try it without `%`

Comment: This was the solution, thank you.